# Org-roam links are considered broken when exporting

Tags: org-export, org-roam

`Org-roam` links are considered broken when exporting. This is annoying as I would like to export those `org` files as pdf documents. I know that the option `broken-links:t` makes the link disappear, and `broken-links:auto` marks the link as broken in the output document.

However, I would like to get either a proper link, or just plain text with the text of the link. Is there a way ?

Comment: You want the org-roam links between documents to be preserved?

Comment: @naugiedoggie that would be a bonus, but the mere description text of the link would already be nice ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was facing the same problem and running `M-x org-roam-update-org-id-locations` before the export did the trick. The links get exported, the description text is there, and if the target file has also been exported, clicking the link takes you there.